# The value of the item is getting displayed while dragging an item using ng2-dragula

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-dragula to get a list of items which can be dragged and dropped. The code is as mentioned below.

.ts file:

```
items = ['Candlestick', 'Dagger', 'Revolver', 'Rope', 'Pipe', 'Wrench' ];
```

.html file:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col col-md-3">                               
        <ul [dragula]='"bag-items"' [dragulaModel]='items'>
            <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">                                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this in a pop up and whenever an item is dragged, the item value is getting printed in the application page behind the pop up. Can somebody suggest me what is causing this?

Comment: Can you attach an image that shows what exactly is happening? Visually?